# Matching the version range for all npm packages

Tags: npm, version, package.json

On my IntelliJ Idea, I get this alert:
`the install version "vue@2.4.2" doesn't match the version range "vue@^2.5.16`

I know how to solve this: yarn install vue@2.5.16.

But I got this problem with all my dependencies. I don't want to solve everything one by one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by the command: `yarn upgrade`

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should [accept it as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) even if [it is your own post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you had the same dependency defined in both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

Remove the dependency from one of these locations and then run `npm install` to fix it.